# Neo4jclient transaction support

Tags: neo4jclient

Does neo4jclient work through the REST endpoint or does neo4jclient interact natively with the neo4j server?

I know neo4j has a rest endpoint and am doubting it's performance for scalability.

Answer (score 2):

It uses the Cypher HTTP API mainly. The only way to not go over HTTP is to run in-process, which isn't really possible from .NET. Another option to investigate is server plugins.